# Keyboard formatting in slack messages?

Tags: slack

Is there a way to get keyboard formatting in slack messages. E.g. something like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> ?

I tried the obvious (what works here on SO) but it didn't work

[image]

Comment: If you downvote, please state why. This is an on-topic, clearly-stated question, with a clear example of the desired behaviour as well as what's been tried so far. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's pretty well restricted to what's available in the Slack UI / listed in their [help article](https://slack.com/intl/en-cl/help/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages).

There are advanced formatting features via the API which are documented [here](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting), but that's limited to mentions, internal links, and date formatting. You can play around with their [message builder](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder) or [block kit builder](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/) to explore a bit more.